# space in the export file Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, spool

i have 1 SQL file as below:

```
set pages 0
set head off
set feedback off
set echo off
set termout off
set wrap off
spool /osp/tmp/bangdd/dumpthe.dump
select a.SERNUM ||','|| b.AMOUNT||','|| b.TOPPF||','|| a.RFPROF from voucher a, SCRATCHP b where b.ri=a.RFPROF and a.sernum='000010263549703';
spool off
```

the out put file with cat -A as below.

```
linus> cat -A dumpthe.dump
000010263549703,20000,020,6                                                     $
```

you can see, there are many space from 6 to $. it make file size is lager than normal. i can use sed command to remove space in the file but i want to know if any option in Oracle SQL can help that?

when i change my query as below

```
set pages 0
set head off
set feedback off
set echo off
set termout off
set wrap off
spool /osp/tmp/bangdd/dumpthe.dump
select a.SERNUM ||','|| b.AMOUNT||','|| b.TOPPF||','|| a.RFPROF || ',' from voucher a, SCRATCHP b where b.ri=a.RFPROF and a.sernum='000010263549703';
spool off
```

the result same as below:

```
linus> cat -A dumpthe.dump
000010263549703,20000,020,6,                                                    $
```

Comment: SQL*Plus has a TRIMSPOOL setting that may solve your problem:

    SET TRIMS[POOL] [ON|OFF]

Comment: excillent. i can help to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to query you posted:

- `000010263549703` is `SERNUM` column's value
- `20000` is `AMOUNT`
- `020` is `TOPF`
- `6                                                     $` is `RFPROF`

There's no evidence that query concatenates `$` at the end of the output string.

Therefore, you got exactly what you have in that column. Someone put bunch of spaces between `6` and `$`. Can you verify that by querying that column only?

If I'm right, and you want to get rid of spaces, replace them with an empty string, e.g.

```
select a.SERNUM ||','|| b.AMOUNT||','|| b.TOPPF||','|| 
--
replace(a.RFPROF, ' ', '')             --> this
--
from voucher a, SCRATCHP b 
where b.ri=a.RFPROF and a.sernum='000010263549703';
```

If I'm wrong, please, post sample data that illustrate that problem so that we could try to recreate it and see what happens.

Comment: RFPROF is 6 only. you see     $ because i use cat -A. you will see where is end of line.

Comment: linus> cat -A dumpthe.dump
000010263549703,20000,020,6                                                     $
nis101 linus> 
this is result with your query.

if i change like that.
set pages 0
set head off
set feedback off
set echo off
set termout off
spool /osp/tmp/bangdd/dumpthe.dump
select a.SERNUM ||','|| b.AMOUNT||','|| b.TOPPF||','|| a.RFPROF || ',' from voucher a, SCRATCHP b where b.ri=a.RFPROF and a.sernum='000010263549703';
spool off
the result same as below:
linus> cat -A dumpthe.dump
000010263549703,20000,020,6,                                                    $

Comment: What is RFPROF column's **datatype**?

Comment: it is number. RFPROF          NUMBER(18)

Comment: OK; I thought that it might be CHAR (which is then right-padded with spaces up to total column length). After all, it seems that it is **TRIMSPOOL** you need (as @p3consulting said). Note that - if line length was fixed (apparently, it is not) - SET LINESIZE might perform better.

Answer (score 1):

after update "set trimspool off" to "set trimspool on". it can help.

```
set pages 0
set head off
set feedback off
set echo off
set termout off
set trimspool on
spool /osp/tmp/bangdd/dumpthe.dump
select a.SERNUM ||','|| b.AMOUNT||','|| b.TOPPF||','|| a.RFPROF || ',' from voucher a, SCRATCHP b where b.ri=a.RFPROF and a.sernum='000010263549703';
spool off
exit
```

result:

```
cat -A dumpthe.dump
000010263549703,20000,020,6,$
```